# IBOutlet connect fails to connect to renamed target

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

So, I was following along a core-data tutorial [RayWenderlich.com part 1/3](https://www.raywenderlich.com/17811/how-to-make-a-simple-mac-app-on-os-x-10-7-tutorial-part-13) circa 2012 using Xcode 8. Naturally some things are different now, like the default view controller and storyboards vs xib being used.

So rather than explicitly creating a xib for the MasterViewController, etc. (I instead did things the Xcode 8 way), I just renamed the supplied ViewController, and the associated .h and .m contents to MasterViewController. All was fine until I got to the step to add its outlet in the app delegate.

[image]

No joy.

[image]

Snippet shows the outlet is there but I cannot link to it.

I uploaded the project to [ScaryBugsMac](https://github.com/slashlos/ScaryBugsMac.git) on github as I'm stuck what's wrong. Tried suggestions on similar question to remove/add, import vs include for the header, and to publish the outlet by putting it in the app delegate header.

I'm thinking the rename isn't being handled but I want to know how it's broken and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I punted and restarted, this time without renaming the controller. Find "part 1" of the tutorial in [ScaryBug](https://github.com/slashlos/ScaryBugs.git) on github.